# Getting \rule to automatically break across lines

Tags: rules

I am currently using `\rule` to insert blank lines into paragraphs of text in a document though the lines often go past the document margins. I know I can use `\hrulefill` to stay within the margins, but often I do not want the line to stretch across the entire page. Does anybody know a way to either have `\rule` break between lines or display wholly on the next line if it does not fit within the margins?

For example:

If I have:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, `\rule{6em}{.5pt}` consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea `\rule{6em}{.5pt}` commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in `\rule{6em}{.5pt}` voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla `\rule{6em}{.5pt}` pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

How can I ensure that the `\rule`s do not cross into my document margins?

Comment: The `exsheets` package has a commend that does this which is based on code by Heiko Obediek: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/de.comp.text.tex/fZLwraH04jE/o1RSdFXjGuIJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To amend the short comment of cgnieder:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
Some people are really modest. Guess who wrote the exsheets package:
The nick of the author is \blank[width=4cm]{cgnieder}, and his full
name is \blank[width=7cm]{Clemens Niederberger}.

\end{document}
```

[image]